# How to switch to the previous pane by any shortcut in tmux?

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

For example, I have three panes in a window with tmux.
Now my cursor is in the second pane. If I use:

```
C-b o
```

I can move to the third pane.

But I want to move to the first pane on the second pane. How to do?

It can list all the panes in one window:

```
C-b q
```

It will show: 0, 1, 2

Is there any key I can press to go to the special pane number? If there is, I can switch to the first pane in a short way, too.

Comment: Following `C-b q`, you can type the pane number while they are still displayed to switch to that pane.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In tmux manual ($man tmux) you can find this section:

```
select-pane [-DdeLlRU] [-t target-pane]
    (alias: selectp)

    Make pane target-pane the active pane in window target-window.   
    If one of -D, -L, -R, or -U is used, respectively the pane below,
    to the left, to the right, or above the target pane is used.  -l
    is the same as using the last-pane command.  -e enables or -d
    disables input to the pane.
```

So, I think what you want is to use the '-l' flag, which is for switch to last pane. I don't know if there is a default key mapping defined to this task, but you can accomplish this by doing your own bindings. Something like this:

```
bind -r <your key> select-pane -l
```

Comment: `^b + ;` is the default shortcut for switching to the last pane.

Comment: @lyuboslavkanev you are a legend.

Comment: note that 'last' is not same as 'previous' in tmux. For windows, you can jump to the 'last' window you were using before the current one; the previous one in tmux's list of windows; or the next one. So 'previous' is tmux's antonym for 'next' and 'last' is a different concept. It appears there is no tmux command for 'previous-pane'. (I'm in tmux 3.1b on macOS right now)

Comment: @JackWasey You are right. There is no default binding to go to the previous pane. But you can create it yourself, e.g.: `bind -T prefix k select-pane -t :.-`

Answer (score 25):

> Copied from  @lyuboslav-kanev

`prefix + ;` worked perfectly for me.

`prefix + l` switch to last window
`prefix + L` switch to last session

Comment: ++ for adding `prefix + l` even though the author of the question didn't ask about it.